# Scrapy as a task

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I recently discovered scrapy and I want to wrote a spider to get urls from my database containing pdf files and download them and remove the record. The issue is that my database will get new records irregularly. That's why I want to run my Crawler as as task every 6 hours.

Any ideas how I can accomplish that?

Here's some code

```
class PDFSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "pdf"

    def __init__(self):
        self.lastUrl = None

    def start_requests(self):
        # get urls from database using django models
         for url in PDFDownloadQueue.objects.all():
         self.lastUrl = url
         yield scrapy.Request(url=url.url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        # write httpresponse as a html file
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-1]
        output = os.path.join(OUTPUT_PATH,filename)
        with open(output, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
        print("Parsed {}".format(self.lastUrl))
```